# Why a change of variables imply $h'$ is never zero?

Tags: differential-geometry

I read the following sentence:

> Suppose $\beta$ is a reparametrization of a parametrized curve $\alpha$, given bt a change of variable $h:[c,d]\to[a,b]$. We know $h$ admits differentiable inverse and hence $h'$ is never zero.

It's not clear to me why these conditions imply the $h'$ is never zero. Can you help me?

Comment: What about the Jacobian of the variables change?

Comment: @Ripi2 Still didn't see it in the course.

Comment: Write down the chain rule for differentiating $h\circ h^{-1}$.

Comment: @TedShifrin I wrote $h(h^{-1}(x))=x$ and hence differentiating both sides we get $h'(h^{-1}(x))\cdot h'^{-1}(x)=1$. So if $h$ is zero, for some value, this would yield a contradiction. Is that it?

Comment: Two errors, but right idea. Can you proofread and correct what you wrote here?

Comment: @TedShifrin Is it that we need to show that $h'^{-1}(x)\neq 0$? Or that $(h^{-1}(x))'$ is the correct notation?

Comment: You continue to write $h’^{-1}$ where you should write $(h^{-1})’$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for $h$ to be a reparametrization of curves ($\beta = \alpha \circ h$), $h$ must be a diffeomorphism between $[a,b]$ and $[c,d]$. In this context, from the Inverse Function Theorem for one real variable,
$$(h^{-1})'(y)=\frac{1}{h'(h^{-1}(y))}\text{ for all }y\in[c,d]$$
And therefore, for it to exist at every point, $h'(h^{-1}(y))\neq 0\ \forall y\in[c,d]$. Since $h^{-1}([c,d])=[a,b]$, the previous statement is equivalent to the following: $h'(x)\neq 0\ \forall x\in[a,b]$.